# Error in C++ class getters that return objects of other class

Tags: c++, class, object, return, getter

I am starting learning C++ and I can not solve this errors. 
I am trying to implement a class called IModeloDinamico that has as private members some objects of another class called FunctionParser implemented in fparser.h library.
I am trying to implement some getters but i have some errors returning the objects of the other class. Here is the code.

```
#//Some includes
#include "fparser.h"

class IModeloDinamico 
{
private:
    //Some string and double variables.

    //FunctionParser variables are objects from fparser library.

    FunctionParser fp1;

    //...

    FunctionParser fp16;

public:

    // Constructor
    IModeloDinamico();

    //Destructor
    ~IModeloDinamico();

    //Accesors

    //Getters

    //Some getters for string and double vars.
    //And getters for return objects of fparser library. **Where i have the errors.**

    FunctionParser GetFunctionParser1() const 
    {
        return fp1;
    };

FunctionParser GetFunctionParser2() const
    {
        return fp2;
    };

// ...

FunctionParser GetFunctionParser16() const
    {
        return fp16;
    };

    //Setters/

    // ...

    //Some methods..
};
```

The error message says:

`‘FunctionParser::FunctionParser(const FunctionParser&)’ is private.`

This method is implemented in fparser library and declared as private member of that class, but I am not calling that method to return that objects.

The other errors are:

`'within this context'`

In every getter of FunctionParser.

Comment: maybe you should return them by reference

Comment: Your post was extremely unreadable. Take care of how you ask questions, because it will impact on quality of answers. This time I edited the question for you, next time please do it yourself.

Comment: Thank you Spook. This is my first message and I was lost!!!! Next time I will do it in the correct way.!!! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The private method is the *copy constructor* and you are calling that method because your methods return a *copy* of the parser object.

```
FunctionParser GetFunctionParser16() const
{
    return fp16; // return copy of fp16
}
```

The fact that the copy constructor is private indicates that the writer of this class did not want these objects to be copied. So you should probably return by reference

```
const FunctionParser& GetFunctionParser16() const
{
    return fp16; // return reference to fp16
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
const FunctionParser& GetFunctionParser1() const { return fp1; }
```

You're not calling the `FunctionParser::FunctionParser(const FunctionParser&)` manually, but when you return it by *value*, it needs to be called to construct *a copy* object that will be returned from your getter.
You might also want to add a non-const getter for const-correctness

```
FunctionParser& GetFunctionParser1() { return fp1; }
```

Comment: const FunctionParser& GetFunctionParser1(){return fp1;};

Comment: What was the problem? Could you explain it to me in a few words. I do not want you to loose your time. Thankyou for the help!!!!